# pouchdb seems to be saving but does not save

Tags: cordova, pouchdb

I'm working on a cordova application. I started using pouchdb because of the insufficient space in the local storage. I post the json data I saved in the local storage area to pouchdb. It's like a document was created. But the document does not occur. Returns 0 lines when I use the Fetch All Documents function.

```js
create: function (item) {
            myApp.db.post(item).then(function (response) {
                console.log("Response id " + response.id + " item " + item);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err.name === 'conflict' ? "Conflict occurred - possible duplicate " : "Error " + err);
            });
  },
    loadData: function (callback) {
        myApp.db.allDocs({ include_docs: true, attachments: true }, function (err, response) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            var rows = response.rows;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                console.log(rows[i].doc);
                alert(JSON.stringify(rows[i].doc));
                //var taskItem = myApp.services.tasks.createTaskElem(rows[i].doc);
                //if (rows[i].doc.completed)
                //    myApp.services.tasks.addToCompletedList(taskItem);
                //else myApp.services.tasks.addToPendingList(taskItem);
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are being tricked by the asynchronous nature of Javascript.  While your `post` command is being processed, Javascript moves on to the next task ... `allDocs` ...  and doesn't find your data because it is still being written to PouchDB.

If you have noticed, each of the PouchDB API document examples have 3 tabs allowing you pick Callback, Promise or Async/Await alternates.  I am sure you will find, once you get the knack of it, that Async/Await is **by far** the best way to work with PouchDB.

So, please try the following instead, and let me know how you get on :

```js
/*  Function to instantiate a new random JSON record */
const item = () => {
  return {
    _id: `Thing_${parseInt(1000*Math.random(), 10)}`,
    stuff: ' silly random remark ',
  }
};

/* Function to 'put', then retrieve, records from PouchDB */
const dbTest = async () => { // "async" advises JavaScript to expect (otherwise illegal) 'await' statements
  console.log(`
    Start ...
    `);
  try {
    /* Remember the item ID */
    const rndItemId = item();

    /* Store the random item in PouchDB */
    const response = await myapp.db.put(rndItemId); // Do NOT return until 'put' is complete

    /* Log the response from PouchDB */
    console.log(`response for <${rndItemId._id}> ....\n${JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}`);

    /* Get back all the random items we 'put' in the Pouch so far */
    const result = await myapp.db.allDocs({ // Do NOT return until 'allDocs' is complete
      include_docs: true,
      attachments: true,
      startkey: 'Thing_0',
      endkey: 'Thing_999',
    });

    /* Log the result from PouchDB */
    console.log(`result ....\n${JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}`);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(`
    ... done!
    `);
};
/* Call the above function */
dbTest();
/* Call it again */
dbTest();
```

Quick note: Notice use of `put` instead of `post`!  Please read [12 pro tips for better code with PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/2014/06/17/12-pro-tips-for-better-code-with-pouchdb.html).